# Elasticsearch desc sorting is not giving current result while asc gives?

Tags: elasticsearch

With elasticsearch results, my order with desc is not opposite as compared to data with asc. Following is my query:

```
{
      "from": 0,
      "size": 15,
      "sort": [
        {
            "orderId" : {
                "order" : "asc" // or "desc"
            }
        }
        ]
}
```

With asc, I am getting following results,

> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_0
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_1
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_10
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_11
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_12
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_2
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_4
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_5
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_6
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_7
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_8
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_9

And with desc, I am getting following results:

> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_4
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_8
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_1
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_11
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_9
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_12
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_5
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_7
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_0
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_2
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_6
>
> 5113c843-dff3-499f-a12e-44c7ac103bcf_10

Any idea why is it so?

Comment: That is weird. The size only is 5, why it can return rows more than 5 ?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the size now. It was my mistake while posting the question.

Comment: Did you try to query on `orderId.keyword`?

Comment: What do you mean by orderId.keyword?

Comment: Could you paste the index creating script here?